# What is the maximum rank difference for a competitive match?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

What is exact rank cap for competitive mode in CS:GO?

For example: I have two friends, a Master Guardian I and a Master Guardian II. What will be lowest rank that will be able to play with them without getting full team(when lobby contains 5 players there seems to be no lock)?

Comment: it might help..https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=312582297

Comment: @Leothelion nothing in that link provides an answer to this question

Comment: well if you will read about rank system then  you will came to know that with whom rank who can play or not which is shown in image also. And i did not said this is the answer. READ BACK, i said it might help. so either come with better solution or stop finding faults in comments.. Thanx

Comment: What do you mean by "without getting full team?" I can possibly answer this question, but I don't know what this means.

Comment: When lobby contains 5 players the rank cap is not a problem

Answer (score 3):

When I was a silver 1 I wasn't able to play with my friend who was a silver elite master. So he switched his account to his silver elite account and we could play.
So you can play with a person that has 5 ranks higher than you, but not 6 or above.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in lobby with 5 players, there is **no lock** - you can be *Silver 1* and your friend can be *Global Elite*, however if you are **not** teamed with 5 players, you are able to play **ONLY** if you are with your friend similar rank - the lock is pretty much few ranks. I dont have correct numbers, but for example, if you are *Gold Nova 3*, and your friend is *Legendary Eagle*, you are not able to play with him. But if you are *Master Guardian 2* and your friend is still *Legendary Eagle*, you can play with him. I don't know correct numbers, but this is my experience.

Comment: I believe it is a 5 rank difference.

Comment: @mordi2k ye, probably 5 is the rank diference, but who knows ;)

Comment: I can confirm the 5 rank difference limit.

Answer (score -1):

The lvl cap is at 6 ranks, I think.

Comment: Do you have any sources for this number?